# GCI returns wrong case of filenames

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing a script to fix text files and replace filenames with their filename in the correct case as it is in Windows.

The problem is GCI, which I know is case insensitive in the search, and returns whatever filename I pass it even if the case is wrong.

For example, if I say `gci "c:\HI.TXT"`  it returns `c:\HI.TXT` even if the filename is really `c:\hi.txt`.

How can I get the correct case for a file?

I need this because the app that the text files are feeding is case sensitive.

Comment: Can you post your code, its really hard to guess what is wrong with a script without seeing exactly what your doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `-Filter` flag you will get the original casing in the output:

```
> echo foo > hi.txt
> gci -Filter HI.TXT


    Directory: C:\git\newrepo


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-----        2013-06-15     17:08          0 hi.txt
```

Comment: It doesn't look like filter takes a path/filename.  I get "Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name" when I do something like gci - filter "c:\test file.txt" Do I have to parse the path into 2 parts and use -path and -filter?

Comment: The problem is a I have a whole path I need to supply to GCI like "c:\data\xyz\filename.txt", not just a filename.  That is why I am saying I think I need to break the path and filename apart and supply the path to the -path and filename to the -filter which is what you did.

Comment: afaik `-filter` only takes filenames, so that is your only option as long as you want to use Klas Mellboum's way.